# Unit testing SuiteScripts and NetSuite Workflows in NetSuite

Tags: unit-testing, scripting, netsuite

I was looking for the options on how to unit test NetSuite SuiteScripts and workflows? Is there any framework for that??

Answer (score 3):

I have used mochajs and chaijs for writing unit tests in NetSuite.

The library needs to be modified a bit as there are some async APIs which won't run in NetSuite.

I have pushed my code on [github](https://github.com/prasunsultania/mochafornetsuite)

You can take a look.

To test a workflow (assuming it runs after a record update/create), you can create/update the record in your unit tests and then write your expectations/assertions after create/update statements

Answer (score 2):

You can unit test your javascript with a js testing framework like QUnit: qunitjs.com

While it wont mock nlapi calls, the rest of your javascript, if structured properly, can be tested with QUnit.

We use this for testing our javascript Netsuite modules.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think anything for unit testing is there in NetSuite.
You can use the debugger to check the RESTlets, Suitelets, UserEvents , Portlets.
For Workflow, you need run it where condition is met and the workflow runs as expected

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Nitish is right. Net suite doesn't have any unit testing functionality like other frameworks do. You can either use the netsuite debugger or manually you have to check the execution log in order to get the stack trace. 
you can use log method 
nlapiLogExecution(type,title,detail) for tracing . But I prefer netsuite Debugger.